# Golang mongodb remove all items from collection [mgo.v2]

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

How to remove all items from collection stored in mongodb using GO lang?

In mongo console I can use:

```
db.mycollection.remove({})
```

where empty brackets {} mean all document pattern.

In GO lang (I use "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" and "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson") there are methods:

```
sess.DB("mydb").C("mycollection").Remove(...)
or
sess.DB("mydb").C("mycollection").RemoveAll(...)
```

but both of them needs parameter that implements selector. For example selector can be a bson map

```
bson.M{"id": id}
```

but I want to remove all elements, not a particular one.

Answer (score 5):

See the MongoDB documentation at:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/

To remove all the documents of a given collection, just call RemoveAll with an empty selector. Just passing nil as a parameter should work fine:

```
sess.DB("mydb").C("mycollection").RemoveAll(nil)
```

Be sure to check the returned objects though.

Comment: Thx, that solved the problem. I did no think that Nil can implement  selector ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per @DidierSpezia response use `C("mycollection").RemoveAll`. However since the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) distinguishes between an "empty object" `{}` and "null", you should probably use an empty `map[string]interface{}` or `bson.M`.

```
sess.DB("mydb").C("mycollection").RemoveAll(bson.M{})
```

Comment: I believe mgo already does this for you. At least, it does it for other methods, such as Find.